# qTranslate in functions.php

Tags: functions

I have a function which redirects user to certain page:

```
wp_redirect('http://address/page');
```

Usually I would just use:

```
<?php _e("<!--:en-->english permalink<!--:--><!--:de-->german permalink<!--:-->"); ?>
```

But this is specific situation and I can't use it this way...

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the previous decision that has to be taken before redirecting?

Comment: Whole function:http://pastebin.com/b4LsXRpg

Comment: You can [edit] your Q and add the code to it. But I don't see how the "language logic" applies in that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are we talking permalinks here or any URL? If any, create an `array( 'en' => 'en_url', 'de' => 'de_url' );` and get the URL by accessing the array using `qtrans_getLanguage()` index.

If you're translating internal permalink use the [`qtrans_convertURL()`](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=9) function.

Comment: Awesome, this works!
Whole code:
http://pastebin.com/fDLbjtrB